# How to make tibble saved with write_tsv readable by read_tsv

Tags: r, dataframe, io, tidyverse, readr

I have quite large `tibble()` (`data.frame`) which I save with `write_tsv()` and would like to read with `read_tsv()`. I am using all default options.
However, `read_tsv()` emits a bunch of warnings (See example below). What strategy could I use to make it work?

(also tried `write_csv()` -> `read_csv()` but same problem).
The solution I have so far is to use `read.csv(..., sep="\t")` but `read.csv()` is substantially slower.

```
> class(PulsarAnnotated2)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
> write_tsv(PulsarAnnotated2, path="PulsarAnnotated2.txt")
> PAnnotated <- read_tsv("PulsarAnnotated2.txt")
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  .default = col_integer(),
  ait_response = col_character(),
  sex = col_logical(),
  rep.delta_npt_score = col_double(),
  rep.rqlq_score_at_inclusion = col_double(),
  rep.rqlq_score_at_evaluation = col_double(),
  aep.delta_csm_score = col_double(),
  DataSet = col_character(),
  sampling_date = col_character(),
  ait_allergen = col_character(),
  R.FileName = col_character(),
  PG.ProteinAccessions = col_character(),
  PG.ProteinGroups = col_character(),
  PG.Quantity = col_double(),
  EG.iRTPredicted = col_double(),
  EG.IsDecoy = col_character(),
  EG.ModifiedSequence = col_character(),
  EG.PrecursorId = col_character(),
  EG.StrippedSequence = col_character(),
  EG.Qvalue = col_double(),
  EG.Svalue = col_double()
  # ... with 7 more columns
)
See spec(...) for full column specifications.
|===============================================================================================================================================| 100%  291 MB
Warning: 1134671 parsing failures.
row # A tibble: 5 x 5 col     row col                 expected               actual file                   expected   <int> <chr>               <chr>                  <chr>  <chr>                  actual 1 16609 sex                 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE     M      'PulsarAnnotated2.txt' file 2 16609 rep.delta_csm_score no trailing characters .52    'PulsarAnnotated2.txt' row 3 16610 sex                 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE     M      'PulsarAnnotated2.txt' col 4 16610 rep.delta_csm_score no trailing characters .52    'PulsarAnnotated2.txt' expected 5 16611 sex                 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE     M      'PulsarAnnotated2.txt'
... ............................ [... truncated]
Warning message:
In rbind(names(probs), probs_f) :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

Comment: WFM: `write_tsv(mtcars, "tmp"); mtcars2 <- read_tsv("tmp")`. Does it work with a subset of your data? If so, perhaps you could provide the data and make a [mcve]. Otherwise, this will be hard to debug.

Comment: @dash2 I do not think that this is an error to debug. I believe this is well known "feature" of readr - try to infer the column types using a  heuristic - analyze 1000 first rows or so. But since I do know the column types (I have the tibble) I am looking for elegant way to persist the information with the data frame. I could store into a second file and pass them later to the col_types - which I do not like because of the 2 files. I could also use dbplyr to store it in sqlite but than I can't inspect the file in an editor which I might want to. So I am wondering if anyone has a nicer idea.

Comment: OK, maybe edit the question to clarify. Obvious first thought, why not just save it using `save` or `saveRDS`?